# systemd protecting /proc: ProtectProc and ProcSubset

Tags: systemd, namespace

I am trying to use systemd's [ProtectProc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectProc=) and [ProcSubset](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProcSubset=) directives to hide "other" processes from the caller:

```
# systemd-run  --wait -p ProtectProc=invisible -p ProcSubset=pid --pty --collect --service-type=exec ls -lh /proc/ | wc -l
Running as unit: run-u2896.service
Press ^] three times within 1s to disconnect TTY.
Finished with result: success
Main processes terminated with: code=exited/status=0
Service runtime: 25ms
CPU time consumed: 8ms
312
```

As we can see, it sees 312 processes inside. We also see `/proc` seems to be mounted correctly:

```
# systemd-run  --wait -p ProtectProc=invisible -p ProcSubset=pid --pty --collect --service-type=exec grep proc /proc/self/mountinfo
<...>
992 971 0:92 / /proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:481 - proc proc rw,hidepid=invisible,subset=pid
<...>
```

Am I understanding correctly what `hidepid=` and `subset=` do? **I would expect to see 1-2 processes here instead of 300+**.

Linux 5.10.0-3-amd64, systemd 247.3-1 (debian bullseye)

Answer (score 2):

Asked [upstream](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/18997), will post here once responded.

Edit: this is possible, but with a non-root user. This has resulted in [documentation updates](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/19001).